# How can I get a class to "reset"?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, dispose

I am writing a C#.NET application. I have a form. When the form is created I create an instance of a class. When I close the form, I want to dispose of the class so that the next time I open the form I can just create a fresh new instance of the class. So, in the form_Closing event I added code like this: `classInstance = null;` The problem is, for some reason, the next time I open the form the class is not equal to null but rather it is in the same state as it was right before I closed the form. Why is this happening?

EDIT: Adding Info:

myHandler is a field in the Form class.
it looks like this:

```
private HSFW_Handler myHandler;
```

The Class that I am referring to is a singleton so I create it like this:

```
    public static HSFW_Handler GetInstance()
    {
        if (myHSFW == null)
        {
            myHSFW = new HSFW_Handler();
            return myHSFW;
        }
        else return myHSFW;
    }
```

I create an initial instance of it in the Form_Shown event

```
    private void SetupDialogForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myHandler = HSFW_Handler.GetInstance();
            UpdateDisplay();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The Form Closing looks like this...

```
private void SetupDialogForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        myHandler = null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a snippet that demonstrates the problem. Both the form creation/show code and the close code.

Comment: "When the form is created I create an instance of a class. " - Are you sure you don't just create another instance of that class when you open the form the next time?

Comment: There is probably something else going on. What else do you do to the class?

Comment: @dtb: I put a break point on the main constructor of the class and it only get's hit the first time the form is opened. I also put a break point in the myHandler = null; line and it does get called when the form is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
public static HSFW_Handler GetInstance()
{
    if (myHSFW == null)
    {
        myHSFW = new HSFW_Handler();
        return myHSFW;
    }
    else return myHSFW;
}
```

And this:

```
private void SetupDialogForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    myHandler = null;
}
```

Notice anything?

You're setting `myHandler` to `null`; but this appears to be an instance-level member of `SetupDialogForm`. Or anyway, it's not the same as `myHSFW`, which is your static variable in the `HSFW_Handler` class.

When you do this...

```
myHandler = HSFW_Handler.GetInstance();
```

...you're making `myHandler` a reference to the same object pointed to by `HSFW_Handler.myHSFW`; but they're still two separate references. Setting one to `null` has no impact on the other.

The point of all this is that you need to actually change the value of `myHSFW` to `null` to get the behavior you seem to want.

I'd do it like this:

```
public class HSFW_Handler
{
    public static void DeleteInstance()
    {
        myHSFW = null;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
private void SetupDialogForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    HSFW_Handler.DeleteInstance();
}
```

Comment: hmmm I see what you mean but I tried it and it still doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: @Jordan: What is in your `HSFW_Handler` constructor?

Comment: Actually I just got it. Your solution worked, I just had to set one other thing to null as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the form_Closing event is being fired, so that you're closing the form and not hiding it?

If so, then search through the code looking for every time classInstance is set to something. You'll probably find the culprit in or around the constructor or another event such as Load or Shown.

Comment: Yes I am sure it's being fired. See the code that I added above.